# How can i do a foreach in a foreach using Blade

Tags: php, foreach, laravel-5

In my controller i did something like this:

```
<?php
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
            $stock = DB::table('stock')
                ->join('quality', 'stock.qualityid', '=', 'quality.qualityid')
                ->select('stock.*', 'quality.name' )
                ->get();
            $data['stock'] = $stock;

        return view('dashboard', $data);
     }
}
?>

and in my view (blade):
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HISFA -- Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
@foreach ($rawmaterial as $rawmaterials)
    <p>Grondstof met naam {{ $rawmaterials->type }} heeft op dit moment een stock van {{ $rawmaterials->quantity }} octabins.</p>
@endforeach
</body>
</html>
```

In my database i have a table (Stock with fields: id, qualityid, height, quantity) and a second table (Quality with fields: qualityid, type)
And now i want from each different type per height the quantity.

Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
            $stock = DB::table('stock')
                ->join('quality', 'stock.qualityid', '=', 'quality.qualityid')
                ->select('stock.*', 'quality.name' )
                ->get();               

        return view('dashboard', ['rawmaterials' => $stock]);
     }
}
?>

and in my view (blade):
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HISFA -- Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
@foreach ($rawmaterials as $rawmaterial)
    <p>Grondstof met naam {{ $rawmaterials->type }} heeft op dit moment een stock van {{ $rawmaterials->quantity }} octabins.</p>
@endforeach
</body>
</html>
```